How to fix the error: Undefined name 'Tflite'
I am currently working on my project that requires me to use a tf model. When I try to run my app using flutter I get an error saying:
lib/main.dart:17:9: Error: Undefined name 'Tflite'.
  await Tflite.loadModel(

I had recently solved some issues regarding the tflite package not being compatible with android v1 and had moved to AndroidV2 or something on the lines of that.
my main.dart file is below:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';
import 'package:tflite_flutter/tflite_flutter.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart';


import 'config/router.dart';
import 'data_model/diagnosis.dart';

const history = "history";
late Box<Diagnosis> historyBox;
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Tflite.loadModel(
    model: "assets/model.tflite",
    labels: "assets/labels.txt",
    numThreads: 1, // defaults to 1
  );
  await Hive.initFlutter();
  Hive.registerAdapter(DiagnosisAdapter());

  //encryption of the hive storage
  final FlutterSecureStorage secureStorage = FlutterSecureStorage();
  var containsEncryptionKey = await secureStorage.containsKey(key: 'encryptionKey');
  if (!containsEncryptionKey) {
    var key = Hive.generateSecureKey();
    await secureStorage.write(key: 'encryptionKey', value: base64UrlEncode(key));
  }
  var encryptionKey = base64Url.decode((await secureStorage.read(key: 'encryptionKey'))!);

  //open the hive storage
  historyBox = await Hive.openBox<Diagnosis>(history, encryptionCipher: HiveAesCipher(encryptionKey));

  runApp(const NaKiFlutter());
}

class NaKiFlutter extends StatelessWidget {
  const NaKiFlutter({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      routerConfig: nakiRouter,
      theme: ThemeData(textTheme: GoogleFonts.robotoTextTheme()),
    );
  }
}

I have tried looking on the web for solutions but I have not found any unluckily. It also doesn't help that I am a beginner at this

There are 2 packages

flutter_tflite
tflite_flutter

You are using the syntax of the first package "TFlite.load_model" while importing the second one. I can see the confusion because of the similar names of those packages.
I suggest you use the second package (tflite_flutter) since it is more updated than the first one.
